# Vector Tiles Projection - PostgreSQL/GeoServer/OpenLayers(Mapbox GL)

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles, geowebcache

I have a dataset in PostgreSQL that is in EPSG:27700, this is read by GoeServer and converted to .pbf files (using GeoWebCache). I have tile gridsets enabled for ESPG:27700,ESPG:4326,ESPG:900913. I am then rendering the tiles using OpenLayers/Mapbox GL.

When using ol.map I get tiles returned and all is working

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      Projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      center: schladmingWebMercator,
      zoom: 18
    }),
    layers: [new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        tilePixelRatio: 1, // oversampling when > 1
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        url: 'http://someserversomewhere:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer +
            '@EPSG%3A'+projection_epsg_no+'@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
      })
    })]
  });
```

However changing to mapbox.gl.map it no longer returns tiles as the map centre is outside my extents

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        minZoom: 15,
        maxZoom: 18,
        style: customStyleJson,
        center: centrepoin,
        zoom: 15,
        url: 'http://someserversomewhere:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer +
            '@EPSG%3A'+projection_epsg_no+'@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'        
    });
```

I'm certain the projection is incorrect or not converting as required but I'm struggling to understand where in the connection a change needs to be made. Could somebody explain at what point a different projection can be requested (without any permanent transformation of data)? I notice the projection setting to 4326 in ol.map, is this possible in Mapbox GL?

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox-gl seems to consider any tile grid to be a standard EPSG:3857 grid.  Using other grids is sometimes possible but will usually involve some messy coding.  I have managed to get other grids to work by making Mapbox-gl think they are standard EPSG:3857 - this requires supplying center coordinates adjusted for where they would be an EPSG:3857 grid instead of where they are on the real grid, and sometimes offsetting the z value in tile requests.  This code https://jsfiddle.net/c209b3t1/ is based on the OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html which integrates a standard Mapbox-gl layer, but has been modified to work with the EPSG:4326 tiles from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tiles-4326.html  I have also successfully used the same technique with the EPSG:27700 grid from https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-vector-tile-api/vts-27700-basic-map